# Numpy calculate difference of matrices against all rows in matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Given two matrices, I want to create a new array of the sum of squared differences of each row, but I cannot seem to find a way.

To be more clear what I mean, let's have an example. I would like to do the following for-loop in numpy matrix calculations:

```
a = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
b = np.array([[1.2, 2.3, 3.4], [4.5, 5.6, 7.8], [9.10, 10.11, 11.12]])
summed = np.ones((2,3))
for i, aSample in enumerate(a):
    for j, bSample in enumerate(b):
       summed[i, j] = np.sum(np.power(aSample - bSample, 2))

>>>summed
array([[ 18.29  , 112.45  , 308.6765],
       [  7.49  ,  79.65  , 251.0165]])
```

These are just example matrices, in my use case both of the matrices have over tens of thousands of rows. So the shapes of these matrices are more like (20000, 1000). Is there a way to do this efficiently with numpy?

EDIT:
@Blorgon provided correct results, but in my case, I couldn't allocate bigger matrix with np.newaxis. The solution by a @MadPhysicist calculated successfully the distance of the vectors within memory limits.

Comment: Not sure I understand your desired result, `summed` ends up as two rows of duplicates...

Comment: Good point, there is a bug. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy solution suggested by [blorgon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69166733/2988730) is likely faster, but you can also use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
>>> cdist(a, b)**2
array([[ 18.29  , 112.45  , 308.6765],
       [  7.49  ,  79.65  , 251.0165]])
```

The problem with this approach is that it takes a square root and then undoes it. The advantage is that it does not use a large intermediate array. You can avoid some intermediates in numpy like this:

```
>>> diff = b - a[:, np.newaxis]
>>> np.power(diff, 2, out=diff).sum(axis=2)
array([[ 18.29  , 112.45  , 308.6765],
       [  7.49  ,  79.65  , 251.0165]])
```

Comment: Surprisingly, timings are similar on my machine: `6.83 µs ± 51.1 ns` for mine vs `7.54 µs ± 30.1 ns` for yours.

Comment: @blorgon. That's a pretty big difference: almost 10+%

Comment: I guess, yeah. I usually look for larger differences than that when comparing different techniques.

Comment: @blorgon. I'm optimizing some embedded code right now, and I would go to great lengths to save 10% on anything :)

Comment: Works as intended, and it worked for my massive matrix! Took couple of minutes to calculate, but still the memory wasn't the limit, like it was with solution @blorgon provided

Comment: @Toothery you should accept this answer then.

Comment: I'll do that, and try to edit the question to be memory-first specific

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.newaxis` to achieve your desired result:

```py
>>> np.sum(np.power(b - a[:, np.newaxis], 2), axis=2)
array([[ 18.29  , 112.45  , 308.6765],
       [  7.49  ,  79.65  , 251.0165]])
```

Edit: while my solution is faster, if memory is important then the `scipy` solution is better.

Comment: Great, works like a charm. Unfortunately, this wont work with my case, as I have too big arrays, and it would require to allocate more than 1TB of RAM for the calculation.

Comment: You may need to consider @MadPhysicist 's answer then. I'm not sure of the memory footprint of that solution, though.

Comment: @blorgon. I've updated mine to help get rid of one of the intermediate arrays

Comment: @Toothery. How big is your test array and what is the dtype?